# All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough'

Tags: scikit-learn, data-science, k-means, scikit-learn-pipeline, tsne

I was studying [In Depth: k-Means Clustering](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/index.html) section from the textbook [Jake VanderPlas's Python Data Science Handbook](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/index.html) and I came across the following code block:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

digits = load_digits()

# Project the data: this step will take several seconds
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, init='random', random_state=0)
digits_proj = tsne.fit_transform(digits.data)

# Compute the clusters
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=10, random_state=0)
clusters = kmeans.fit_predict(digits_proj)
```

This code from the book (I've changed a little bit for clarity of my question, you can view the original code from the first link) runs without any problems. Then I tried to construct a pipeline by `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` with the models from above. Here is my code:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

digits = load_digits()

estimators = [('reduce_dim', TSNE(n_components=2, init='random', random_state=0)),
              ('cls', KMeans(n_clusters=10, random_state=0))]

pipe = Pipeline(estimators)

clusters = pipe.fit_predict(digits.data)
```

I tried to run my code but every time I got the error message

> TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough' 'TSNE(init='random', random_state=0)' (type ) doesn't

The thing is `TSNE()` step is a transformer and also implements fit and transform. We can see this from the original code from book

```py
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, init='random', random_state=0)
digits_proj = tsne.fit_transform(digits.data)
```

But the error message says the opposite. I read scikit-learn's doc (specifically, [sklearn.manifold.TSNE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html#sklearn.manifold.TSNE) and [Pipelines and composite estimators](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html)) but doc gave nothing to solve my problem. What do you think the problem is?

Comment: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/16710